# Passing values using intent extras in Alarm Manager in android

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I want to know if this code will work(I cannot try it out right now. Moreover, I have a few doubts that have to be cleared).

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
intent.putExtra("user",global.getUsername());
intent.puExtra("password",global.getPassword);
PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 192837, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
// Get the AlarmManager service
Log.v("inside log_run", "new service started");
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, IMMEDIATELY,60000,sender);
finish();
```

As you can see, this code starts an `AlarmManager` with `setRepeating()`. If you see the intent(actually the pending intent) passed on to the `BroadcastReceiver`, there are two extras that are passed on. These are global variables that live as long as the Application is running. But this `AlarmManager` is meant to be run in the background (that is application will be alive only for the first few calls of the of the alrmamanager to the broadcast recevier)

**My Question**

Will AlarmManager make a copy of the global variables(the username and password) and maintain this copy to be passed along with the intent (as extras)? Or will it reference the global variables (in the process pass null as the extra when the global variables become null)? Because, these values will be used in the broadcast receiver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see problems arising from this method. What I would do is store your two variables in a SharedPrefs file and access them from the BroadcastReciever directly. SharedPrefs values persist while "global variables" in Android do not.

Comment: I thought of this method. But the shared preferences are stored in a xml file. These files, if exported can be seen by anyone. But not global variables.

Comment: SharedPrefs are private by default, to quote the docs - "the created file can only be accessed by the calling application (or all applications sharing the same user ID)."

Comment: You are right about that. But what I am trying to say is that, what if I connect my phone to my PC and in Eclipse using DDMS, can I export the XML file to my PC. This can be done with DB. An Applications database can be exported this way.

Comment: Ahhh, I had not considered this.

Comment: I think your solution might work because, the xml file cannot be exported when the phone is not rooted.

Comment: I accept that it is a solution to my problem. But I am still waiting for an answer without the use of sharedpreference. I will accept your answer till then.

Answer (score 0):

On the Alarm manager, simply pass getApplicationContext as a parameter to the helper contructor.