# Android service gets killed on swiping out the application

Tags: android, service

I have an Android Service class the code for which is as follows:

```
public class LoginService extends Service {
BroadcastReceiver wifiStateChangeReciever;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i("AndroidLearning", "Service onStartCommand Started.");
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.i("AndroidLearning", "Service Started.");

    final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    // intentFilter.addAction("android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED");
    intentFilter.addAction("android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE");
    wifiStateChangeReciever = new WifiStateChangeReciever();
    this.registerReceiver(wifiStateChangeReciever, intentFilter, null, null);

    Log.i("AndroidLearning", "Reciever Registered.");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.i("AndroidLearning", "Service Destroyed.");
    this.unregisterReceiver(wifiStateChangeReciever);
}

@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    Log.w("AndroidLearning", "On Task Remove: FLAG_STOP_WITH_TASK - "
            + ServiceInfo.FLAG_STOP_WITH_TASK);
    this.unregisterReceiver(wifiStateChangeReciever);
    Intent restartServiceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
    this.getClass()); restartServiceIntent.setPackage(getPackageName());
    PendingIntent restartServicePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
            getApplicationContext(), 1, restartServiceIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT); 
    AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmService.setExact(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
            SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000, restartServicePendingIntent); 
    Log.w("AndroidLearning", "End on task removed");
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);

}
}
```

It registers a `BroadcastReciever`. The Activity which starts this service has the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginService.class);
startService(intent);
```

However whenever the Activity is swiped out from the task list (recent) the service is also stopped. I over rode the `onTaskRemoved` to remedy it but it still does not seem to work and the AlarmManager never starts the `pendingIntent`. I have tries using both method: `set` and `setExact` for the `AlarmManager`.

I also tried adding the following options to `<service>` tags

```
android:stopWithTask="false"
android:process=":remote"
```

but to no avail.

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks for the help.

Comment: on Android 5.01, I've tried swiping my app away - and the service is killed (it's local and within same process) - but because I started it as a sticky service I see that Android relaunches the service

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found the answer to my own problem. It seems this was a problem with the particular flavor of android that I was running on my phone (Mi UI). There was a separate setting regarding each application whether it needed to be allowed to be restarted or not.

[image: Screenshot - autostart is the setting that I was looking for]

Unless this setting is configured no amount of changing permissions and setting Alarms helped me.

Comment: Thanks! My code was correct but due to this problem i wasted my 2 day. Thanks a lot. Can you tell me how can we get this permission after first open of app.?

Comment: In some phones like Mi and Vivo, we have to change the settings and give the app special permission to run in background from the settings app. Even if you have made a service that auto-restarts when the app is closed, the service won't run until and unless you set permissions in the settings app of your phone.

Answer (score 1):

This is a different approach from you but I recently fixed this by adding a notification when the service was running

```
  private void showNotification(){
    NotificationCompat.Builder builer = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
            .setContentTitle("Service active")
            .setContentText("Your service keeps running")
            .setOngoing(true);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builer.build());

}
```

The notification is shown in onStartCommand and dismissed in the service ondestroy method.

Comment: That would probably take up more battery? I dont need a foreground process always.

Comment: I'm afraid this is the only way to prevent your service from closing when swiping your activity out of the task list. The alarmmanager will be able to reboot your service but it won't be until your alarm gets triggered.

Comment: Then how does a service like whatsapp function. As soon as I kill it it restarts. Also what do you mean by 'until alarm gets triggered'?

Answer (score 1):

You need to start service in foreground if you don't want android to shut it down.

```
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, getText(R.string.ticker_text),
    System.currentTimeMillis());
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ExampleActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, getText(R.string.notification_title),
    getText(R.string.notification_message), pendingIntent);
startForeground(ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground

Answer (score 1):

If you try this on some devices, sadly, it won't work.

Some OEMs decided to change the normal behavior of what happens when you remove an app from the recent tasks, so they become semi-disabled:

- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122098785
- https://dontkillmyapp.com/