# Android prevent service from being killed by application manager

Tags: android, android-studio, android-service

Currently I'm trying to prevent my service from being killed by application manager. Everytime I swipe the application, service is also killed.

What I have tried is
1. using START_STICKY

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand started");



        if(!isRunning){
            mythread.start();
            isRunning = true;
        }
   return START_STICKY;
}
```

In this example, my thread is showing toast every five seconds.

I also created a Broadcast Receiver and gave a service separate process

```
<service android:name="com.example.asd.mainhub.GPSTracker"
                 android:process=":my_process"
                 android:enabled="true" />

        <receiver android:name="com.example.asd.mainhub.BootCompletedIntentReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_RESTARTED" />
                <action android:name="com.example.asd.mainhub.BootCompletedIntentReceiver" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

onDestroy() method for service, which will use broadcast receiver to restore my service, didn't work.

public void onDestroy() {

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.asd.mainhub.BootCompletedIntentReceiver");
intent.putExtra("yourvalue", "torestore");
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

}

MainActivity, calling my service onCreate()

```
    gps = new GPSTracker();
    mServiceIntent = new Intent(this, gps.getClass());

    if (!isMyServiceRunning(gps.getClass())) {

        startService(mServiceIntent);
    }
```

I've also tried to use notification and foreground onCreate() of service:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
        notificationIntent, 0);

Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle("My Awesome App")
        .setContentText("Doing some work...")
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();

startForeground(1337, notification);
```

Still same, every time I swap my application, service is also dies, and no Toasts are shown anymore. In my console the last messages are:
I/MAINACT: onDestroy!
Application terminated.
Seems like the service onDestroy() method is not even called. Please suggest something, how can i solve this.

P.S btw is I install app as a system app, will it solve the issue ?

EDIT1:

```
private final class ServiceHandler extends Handler {
        public ServiceHandler(Looper looper) {
            super(looper);
        }
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            // Normally we would do some work here, like download a file.
            // For our sample, we just sleep for 5 seconds.
//            try {
//                Thread.sleep(5000);
//            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
//                // Restore interrupt status.
//                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
//            }

            while(isRunning){
                Log.d(TAG,"Running");

                try {
                    postToastMessage("Toast from Service");
                    Thread.sleep(DELAY);

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    isRunning = false;
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            // Stop the service using the startId, so that we don't stop
            // the service in the middle of handling another job
            //stopSelf(msg.arg1);
        }
    }

    public void postToastMessage(final String message) {
        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

        handler.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

    static final long DELAY = 5000;
```

EDIT 2:

```
HelloService service = new HelloService();

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Intent intent = new Intent(this, service.getClass());

        if (!isMyServiceRunning(service.getClass())) {

            //startService(mServiceIntent);
            startService(intent);
        }
```

Comment: `"I'm trying to prevent my service from being killed [...] "`, you cannot do that, mission impossible

Comment: Can you explain why ? Is it rly impossible to create something like a system service which will be running despite my app is open or closed ?

Comment: Why alot of articles and tutorials on this topic and people say it works

Comment: why? would you like to run some malicious service that you couldn't kill? i wouldn't

Comment: and if `"alot of articles and tutorials"` say its possible, then follow them

Comment: As you can see from my qualification I've followed alot of them already, and some people say it works, some say it doesnt. That s why I posted here my question, so that a professionals can give me advice. If you don't know how just walk away

Comment: so what do you expect? i already said that it cannot be done, would you like to have some malicious service that couldn't be killed?

Comment: Read my previous reply again

Comment: Solution was fount in this post, I'm also a MiUI user, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29607856/android-service-gets-killed-on-swiping-out-the-application

Answer (score 1):

Use intent service instead of service, it runs on worker thread not main thread. So will keep running when application is removed from task manager.

Comment: IntentServices are for single fire-and-forget things, not for long running tasks

Comment: you can pass queue of tasks, or start service again without checking its running or not.

Answer (score -1):

What you're looking for is [Services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html). You're most recommended to read the documention by Android Studio [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html).

Services will allow a very specific part of your application to survive at all times. Even when the user restart their devices and never run your application again. There is a lot to perceive about Services, but at the moment I believe a snippet will be most helpful to you, here is a little code,

First in your manifest

```
    <!--notification-->
    <service android:name="services.HelloService"
        android:exported="false"
        android:description="My notification Center"/>
    <!--notification-->
```

Second

Create a class called ***HelloService***

and paste the following code inside with the proper imports*

```
public class HelloService extends Service {
private Looper mServiceLooper;
private ServiceHandler mServiceHandler;

// Handler that receives messages from the thread
 private final class ServiceHandler extends Handler {
  public ServiceHandler(Looper looper) {
      super(looper);
  }
  @Override
  public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
      // Normally we would do some work here, like download a file.
      // For our sample, we just sleep for 5 seconds.
      try {
          Thread.sleep(5000);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          // Restore interrupt status.
          Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
      }
      // Stop the service using the startId, so that we don't stop
      // the service in the middle of handling another job
      stopSelf(msg.arg1);
  }
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
// Start up the thread running the service.  Note that we create a
// separate thread because the service normally runs in the process's
// main thread, which we don't want to block.  We also make it
// background priority so CPU-intensive work will not disrupt our UI.
HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("ServiceStartArguments",
        Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
thread.start();

// Get the HandlerThread's Looper and use it for our Handler
mServiceLooper = thread.getLooper();
mServiceHandler = new ServiceHandler(mServiceLooper);
  }

  @Override
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
   Toast.makeText(this, "servicestarting",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


  Message msg = mServiceHandler.obtainMessage();
  msg.arg1 = startId;
  mServiceHandler.sendMessage(msg);

  // If we get killed, after returning from here, restart
  return START_STICKY;
      }

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
   // We don't provide binding, so return null
   return null;
          }


 @Override
 public void onDestroy() {
   Toast.makeText(this, "service done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
}
```

Now, inside the 'handleMessage Method' add your bit of code, for example ;

```
  @Override
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

 //... your bit of code goes here
```

try {
          Thread.sleep(5000);

```
         // make a toast appears here 

  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      // Restore interrupt status.
      Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
  }
    //stopSelf(msg.arg1);  //... kill the service in your condition
}
```

Lastly, to activate the service class, in your function to trigger the service, first import the HelloService.class, then create an Intent and fire up!

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, HelloService.class);
 startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: I'll try you code in a short while, but using your method is it possible to do a constant task in a service, like sending http get request ?

Comment: precisely, and for instance, you could check whether or not the network is available first and then proceed with your http request.

Comment: I've tried to use your code but still same. ill wrote EDIT1 to show what i've applied, everytime i kill my app service is stopped and no longer make toasts

Comment: I forgot to mention how you can activate the service, in your desired function to trigger all of this first import services.HelloService;
 then start the following activity 
Intent intent = new Intent(this, HelloService.class);

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(this, HelloService.class);

        if (!isMyServiceRunning(gps.getClass())) {

            //startService(mServiceIntent);
            startService(intent);
        }
Like this ?

Comment: @d123546 I can hardly read your code, kindly try and edit your post.

Comment: Still same :( swiping kills everything. Is it Android 6 protection or something ? I've started service in MainActivity onCreate() is that correct ?

Comment: Edit 2, please have a look :)

Comment: @d123546 clearly something is not written correctly. Do worry not. The service can be active 24/7. In the handleMessage Function make a Toast which appears after 10 seconds while the app is closed and see what happens

Comment: try {
          Thread.sleep(5000);   //toast here
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          // Restore interrupt status.
          Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
      }

Comment: Says nothing about weather this survives application kill, or when android will kill your application when memory is low. etc.