# Xamarin Forms Background Thread

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I searched but couldn't find it. That's why I had to ask here. My question is:

I have a thread. While the thread is running and the application is in sleep mode, some android phones terminate the program and thread but some phones don't. What can I do in this situation?

Comment: Hi , you mean part of android phones not working ? Could you share the code in question .

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to check your code on different Android versions. Android Documentation stated background api changes.

- [Android 10](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/behavior-changes-all)
- [Pie](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-all)
- [Oreo](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background)
- [Nougat](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes)

Also you can look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12219249/background-service-getting-killed-in-android).